# How to Install CA Certificate on Android devices in AWS Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm, mobileiron

As per our requirements we are expected to install our CA certificates on end user devices (for Android) manually or pushed the certificates though MobileIron service for our users. After successful installation of CA Certificates only, our App Users can benefit our services.

As of now i don’t see any option to install CA Certificates on Android Device which is located in AWS Device Farm before running my appium tests.

is there any way to achieve it or any one successful with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a supported scenario for Device Farm today.

Device Farm will review the requirements for possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks Hongda Zhao.